# parallel loop over pairs

Tags: multithreading, c++11

What is the best way in C++11 to perform a pairwise computation in multiple threads? What I mean is, I have a `vector` of elements, and I want to compute a function for each pair of distinct elements. The caveat is that I cannot use the same element in multiple threads at the same time, e.g. the elements have states that evolve during the computation, and the computation relies on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to group the pairs by offsets.

If v is a vector, then the elements N apart (mod v.size()) form two collections of pairs.  Each of those collections of pairs contain no overlaps inside themselves.

Examine a 10 element vector `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.  The pairs 1 apart are:

```
0 1, 1 2, 2 3, 3 4, 4 5, 5 6, 6 7, 7 8, 8 9, 9 0
```

if you split these by "parity" into two collections we get:

```
0 1, 2 3, 4 5, 6 7, 8 9 
1 2, 3 4, 5 6, 7 8, 9 0
```

You can work, in parallel, on each of the above collections.  When the collection is finished, sync up, then work on the next collection.

Similar tricks work for 2 apart.

```
0 2, 1 3, 4 6, 5 7
2 4, 3 5, 6 8, 7 9
```

with leftovers:

```
8 0, 9 1
```

For every offset from 1 to n/2 there is are 2 "collections" and leftovers.

Here is offset of 4:

```
0 4, 1 5, 2 6, 3 7
4 8, 5 9, 6 0, 7 1
```

and leftovers

```
8 2, 9 3
```

(I naively think the size of leftovers is vector size mod offset)

Calculating these collections (and the leftovers) isn't hard; arranging to queue up threads and get the right tasks efficiently in the right threads is harder.

There are N choose 2, or (n^2+n)/2, pairs.  This split gives you O(1.5n) collections and leftovers, each of size at most n/2, and full parallelism within each collection.

---

If you have a situation where some elements are far more expensive than others, and thus waiting for each collection to finish idles threads too much, you could add fine-grained synchronization.

Maintain a vector of atomic bools.  Use that to indicate that you are currently processing an element.  Always "lock" (set to true, and check that it was false before you set it to true) the lower index one before the upper one.

If you manage to lock both, process away.  Then clear them both.

If you fail, remember the task for later, and work on other tasks.  When you have too many tasks queued, wait on a condition variable, trying to check and set the atomic bool you want to lock in the spin-lambda.

Periodically kick the condition variable when you clear the locks. How often you do this will depend on profiling.  You can kick without aquiring the mutex mayhap (but you must sometimes acquire the mutex after clearing the bools to deal with a race condition that could starve a thread).

Queue the tasks in the order indicated by the above collection system, as that reduces the likelihood of threads colliding.  But with this system, work can still progress even if there is one task that is falling behind.

It adds complexity and synchronization, which could easily make it slower than the pure collection/cohort one.

Comment: Naively, it looks like if I have a given number of threads, then using this approach I may have a situation in which I have to wait to be completely done with the current collection to move on to the next one, and therefore not fully utilize system resources during that period. Or is there a queueing trick that alleviates that problem?

Comment: @SU3 If you want to fully use system resources, have extra threads spin: "fully using system resources" seems like a bad goal.  Finish fast seems a better one!  My goal was to keep synchronization to a minimum (1.5n times, after every collection) and keep a high degree of parallelism, with the belief that synchronization is a high-overhead problem (which will sure keep your resource utilization high if you use it lots!)  Are some of your element processing orders of magnitude slower than others?  If so, a find-grained locking mechanism that maybe just uses the above for queue order mayhap.

Comment: @SU3 details added to answer.